# reorder the csv file by index column with predefined order

Tags: python, pandas, csv, row

I'm trying to reorder the csv file I generated with python, and can't make it work,

The data is as:

```
metrics   test1 test2 test3 test4 ...
aa-key1
aa-key3
bb-key4
cc--key2
dd--key5
...
```

the keys are not in not sorted alphabetical nor numerical.  It's just need to be as a predefined order [key1, key2, key3, key4, key5].  I added aa, cc, bb dd to illustrate the order I always got.  It's there any way I can re-order the table by the first column, and the CSV would like

```
metrics   test1 test2 test3 test4 ...
aa-key1
cc--key2
aa-key3
bb-key4
dd--key5
...
```

I had generated the csv with panda, by appending the columns after creation.  Although I defined the dictionary as orderedDict, the order doesn't seem to take affected.

```
def create_csv(infile, result):
    dict = parse_log_to_dict(infile)

    with open(result, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['metrics', get_file_name_only(infile)])
        for row in dict.items():
           writer.writerow(row)
```

I tried with:

```
  PREPERED_INDEX = [key1, key2, key3, key4, key5]
  reporter_df = pd.read_csv(result, index_col=0)
  reporter_df[0] = pd.Categorical(reporter_df[0], PREPERED_INDEX)
    reporter_df.sort_values('metrics')
    reporter_df.to_csv(result)
```

but got keyError on metrics, which is the title line I meant to be in the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I created a csv with data similar to what you seem to have, I used the delimiter=";" because my .csv was seperated that way you likely dont need it:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Dokumente\example.csv", delimiter=";")
```

Output:

```
    metrics  test1
0   key1         1
1   key4         4
2   key2         2
3   key5         5
4   key3         3
```

Then if you simply sort it by your column "metrics" it should do what you want to achieve:

```
df = df.sort_values("metrics")
```

Output:

```
  metrics  test1
0    key1      1
2    key2      2
4    key3      3
1    key4      4
3    key5      5
```

I believe by using index_col=0 you are using that entire column as index and it cant be accessed via the key "metrics" any longer. Atleast for me that seems to be the problem here when I try to reproduce it.

Additionally if you are worried about the messed up index you can then reset it in the next step with:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which then returns this for df:

```
  metrics  test1
0    key1      1
1    key2      2
2    key3      3
3    key4      4
4    key5      5
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, the key1-key5 are arbitrary names for example: 'auto(key2), bike(key1), car(key4), drum (key3)', i don't want them to be sorted, but with the pre defined order as PREPERED_INDEX = [bike, auto, drum, car].  but my result aways comes back with sorted alphabetically: auto, bike, car, drum